# Pig - passing Databag to UDF constructor

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a script which is loading some data about venues:

```
venues = LOAD 'venues_extended_2.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader() AS (Name:chararray, Type:chararray, Latitude:double, Longitude:double, City:chararray, Country:chararray);
```

Then I want to create UDF which has a constructor that is accepting venues type.

So I tried to define this UDF like that:

```
DEFINE GenerateVenues org.gla.anton.udf.main.GenerateVenues(venues);
```

And here is the actual UDF:

```
public class GenerateVenues extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

    private static final String ALLCHARS = "(.*)";
    private ArrayList<String> venues;

    private String regex;

    public GenerateVenues(DataBag venuesBag) {
        Iterator<Tuple> it = venuesBag.iterator();
        venues = new ArrayList<String>((int) (venuesBag.size() + 1)); // possible fails!!!
        String current = "";
        regex = "";
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Tuple t = it.next();
            try {
                current = "(" + ALLCHARS + t.get(0) + ALLCHARS + ")";
                venues.add((String) t.get(0));
            } catch (ExecException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("VenuesRegex: requires tuple with at least one value");
            }
            regex += current + (it.hasNext() ? "|" : "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        // expect one string
        if (tuple == null || tuple.size() != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "BagTupleExampleUDF: requires two input parameters.");
        }
        try {
            String tweet = (String) tuple.get(0);
            for (String venue: venues)
            {
                if (tweet.matches(ALLCHARS + venue + ALLCHARS))
                {
                    Tuple output = mTupleFactory.newTuple(Collections.singletonList(venue));
                    return output;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(
                    "BagTupleExampleUDF: caught exception processing input.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

When executed the script is firing error at the `DEFINE` part just before `(venues);`:

```
2013-12-19 04:28:06,072 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file script.pig, line 6, column 60>  mismatched input 'venues' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, can you help me out figuring out what's wrong.
Is it the UDF that cannot accept the venues relation as a parameter. Or the relation is not represented by `DataBag` like this `public GenerateVenues(DataBag venuesBag)`?
Thanks!

PS I'm using Pig version **0.11.1.1.3.0.0-107**.

Answer (score 4):

As @WinnieNicklaus already said, you can **only** pass strings to UDF constructors.

Having said that, the solution to your problem is using distributed cache, you need to override `public List<String> getCacheFiles()` to return a list of filenames that will be made available via distributed cache. With that, you can read the file as a local file and build your table.

The downside is that Pig has no initialization function, so you have to implement something like

```
private void init() {
    if (!this.initialized) {
        // read table
    }
}
```

and then call that as the first thing from `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a relation as a parameter in a UDF constructor. Only strings can be passed as arguments, and if they are really of another type, you will have to parse them out in the constructor.