# How to subtract 2 values in a bag?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here's what I do so far:
Input data (example):

> msg_snd,1,3,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523661,9
>
> res_rcv,1,3,13,err,0,1414250523662,9

Loading:

```
clientlog = LOAD '/user/hduser/pva4/input/client_example.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (code:chararray, client_id:int, loc_ts:int, length:int, op:chararray, err_code:int, time:long, thread_id:int);
```

Grouping:

```
g1 = GROUP clientlog BY (client_id, loc_ts);
g2 = FOREACH g1 GENERATE $1.time;
```

The output for this is (example):

> ({(1414250525776),(1414250525785)})
>
> ({(1414250525793),(1414250525785)})
>
> ({(1414250525793),(1414250525800)})
>
> ({(1414250525800)})
>
> ({()})

Most bags have 2 tuples in them. The other with 0 or 1 I can filter out I suppose.
What I'm trying to achieve now is: Subtract one value from the other to get kind of a "response-time" (these are log-data).
Is there a way in plain pig-latin to do this?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hi @Chrispingu, could you please provide a bit more information about your problem? The code you're working with and an error message if there is one will help a lot in answering your question.

Comment: Hi Luke, there is no error yet, I'm just stuck with the resulting bags trying to subtract their values, like this: ({(1414250525776),(1414250525785)}) Should become something like ABS(1414250525776-1414250525785) which is ABS(-9)=9. So I'm really just trying to get the difference for both numbers in each line, which sounds so easy, but I found no solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

you can write your custom `EvalFunc<String>` udf to substract two values available in a bag, use below line for foreach,

```
g2 = FOREACH g1 {GENERATE CUSTOM_UDF(g1);}
```

And how to write UDF [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682407/pig-passing-databag-to-udf-constructor) can be useful

Answer (score 0):

USE UDF to subtract the elements in the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, is to multiply the first tuple by `-1` then apply the `sum` function :

```
g2 = FOREACH g1 GENERATE -1*$1.time.$0;
g3 = FOREACH g2 GENERATE FLATTEN(group),SUM(g1.time);
```

For bags with less than two tuples use `bincond` to process them differently.